# My variables won't append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm running this html document with javascript/JQuery and after answering the prompt, nothing happens. It seems like the append function isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>
                Rock Paper Scissors
            </title>
            <script>
                var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, scissors lizard or spock?");
                userChoice = userChoice.toLowerCase();
                var computerChoice = function(){
                    var choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors", "lizard", "spock"];
                    var random = Math.random();
                    var loop = true;
                    while (loop){
                        i = 0.2;
                        j = 0;
                        if (random <= i){
                            var choices = choices[j]
                            var loop = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            i = i +0.2;
                            j ++;
                        }
                    }
                    return choices;
                };
            $(document).ready(function(){$("body").append(userChoice);});
            $(document).ready(function(){$("body").append(computerChoice());});
        </script>
        </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use the same variable `choices` for the array and also the chosen selection. I think it works OK in this case, but it's really confusing.

Comment: You forgot to include jquery library

Comment: And instead of setting `loop = false`, you can just use `break;` to terminate a loop.

Answer (score 3):

A few things wrong with this.

1. you didn't include jQuery as others have pointed out
2. you use the variable choices twice for two different values
3. your loop is all wrong, j is reset to 0 every time, so you are
   always going to select "rock"
4. you don't actually need a loop, you just need to pick a random
   member of an array

I have cleaned it up a bit for you - jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/7DWhL/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var userChoice = "",
    computerChoice = "",
    choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors", "lizard", "spock"];


$(document).ready( function(){
  userChoice = prompt( "Do you choose rock, paper, scissors lizard or spock?" );
  userChoice = userChoice.toLowerCase();
  computerChoice = choices[ Math.floor( choices.length * Math.random() ) ];

  $( "body" ).append( "<p>" + userChoice + "</p>" );
  $( "body" ).append( "<p>" + computerChoice + "</p>" );
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you get an infinite loop because you set i = 0.2 inside the loop.

Try this (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5c25t/2/) :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

                var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, scissors lizard or spock?");
                userChoice = userChoice.toLowerCase();
                var computerChoice = function(){
                    var choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors", "lizard", "spock"];
                    var random = Math.random();
                    var loop = true;
                    var i = 0.2;
                    var j = 0;
                    while (true){
                        if (random <= i){
                            return choices[j]                            
                        }
                        else {
                            i=i+ 0.2;
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                    return choices;
                };
           $("body").append(userChoice);
           $("body").append(computerChoice());

});
```